# Draw adjacent related plots from different dataframes on the same png

Tags: r

I have two dataframes called `ret` and `raw`. I process the data frames individually so that each one outputs a series of plots. Each plot represents a different chromosome. Both data frames are grouped by the same chromosomes (but the x axis and y axis for each data frame measure different things so the data cant be merged together). I would like the output to show the plots for Chromosome from the data frame `ret` (called `ret$chr`) to be adjacent to the same chromosome from data frame `raw` (called `raw$Chromosome`). At the moment my code is:

```
# Plot the bins and sums for each chromosome. (png,pdf,ps,tiff)
ind = unique(as.character(ret$chr))
ind2 = unique(as.character(raw$Chromosome))
png(filename=paste("/Users/blabla/Desktop/SequencingScripts/Plots/temp","png"), width = 600, height = 2000)
par(mfrow=c(8,3), mar = rep(0.5, 4), oma = rep(0.5, 4))

for(jj in ind){
indic = which(ret$chr == jj)
indic2 = which(raw$Chromosome == jj)
plot(ret$retxvalue[indic],ret$retyvalue[indic],pch=19,xlab="Locus",ylab="Summed ZScore",type="s",main=jj,lwd=2, ylim=c(-1,2.5))
plot(raw$rawxvalue[indic2],raw$rawyvalue[indic2],pch=19,xlab="Locus",ylab="Ratio",type="s",main=jj,lwd=2, ylim=c(-1,2.5)xlim=c(0,20000))
}
dev.off()
```

However I keep getting the error:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it a copy paste error ?
(seems you lost a coma)

```
 ylim=c(-1,2.5)xlim=c(0,20000)
```